# Connect a List to another List

Tags: java, list

I have a list and want to connect this to another list in java. The first list calculates a shortest path and the other list has the waypoints for the car. When I've got an answer from the shortest path I want to connect this to the waypoints

```
package Main;

import PathfindingEasy.DijkstraAlgorithm;
import PathfindingEasy.Edge;
import PathfindingEasy.Graph;
import PathfindingEasy.Vertex;
import com.jme3.asset.AssetManager;
import com.jme3.scene.Node;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author NathanStowers
 */
public class PathFinder {
Node rootNode;
AssetManager assetManager;
private List<Vertex> nodes;
private List<Edge> edges;

PathFinder(Node rootNode, AssetManager assetManager) {
    this.rootNode = rootNode;
    this.assetManager = assetManager;
}

public void pathExcute() {
    nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    edges = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 317; i++) {
        Vertex location = new Vertex(i, "Node_" + i);
        nodes.add(location);
    }
    ListHandler lh = new ListHandler(rootNode, assetManager);
    //dummy data
    for (int i = 0; i < 78; i++){
        addLane("lLane1_"+i, i, i + 1, 10);
    }
    addLane("lLane1_78", 0, 78, 780);

    for (int i = 79; i < 157; i++){
        addLane("rLane1_"+i, i, i + 1, 10);
    }
    addLane("rLane_157", 79, 157, 780);
    addLane("connectlL1_rL1_1", 78, 79, 300);
    addLane("connectlL1_rL1_2", 157, 0, 300);

    for (int i = 78; i > 0; i--) {
        addLane("lLane2_"+i, i, i - 1, 10);
    }
    addLane("lLane2_78", 78, 0, 780);

    for (int i = 157; i > 79; i--) {
        addLane("rLane2_"+i, i, i - 1, 10);
    }
    addLane("rLane_157", 157, 79, 780);
    addLane("conectlL2_rL2_1", 79, 78, 300);
    addLane("connectlL2_rL2_2", 0, 157, 300);

    int k = 162;
    for (int i = 43; i < 79; i += 5) {
        addLane("bargeLane_" + i, i, k, 10);
        k += 3;
    }

    int j = 40;
    for (int i = 160; i < 182; i += 3) {
        addLane("bargeLane_" + i, i, j, 10);
        j += 5;
    }

    int h = 162;
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i+=2){
        addLane("underBargeCrane_" +i, h, h-1, 10);
        addLane("underBargeCrane_" +i+1, h-1, h-2, 10);
        h+=3;
    }

    for (int i = 190; i < 211; i++) {
        addLane("underTrainCrane_" + i, i, i + 1, 10); 
    }
    addLane("connectToTrain_1", 79, 190, 10);
    addLane("conectToTrain_2", 211, 97, 10);

    for (int i = 220; i < 226; i++) {
        addLane("topLaneL_" + i, i, i + 1, 33);
    }

    for (int i = 230; i < 236; i++) {
        addLane("topLaneR_" + i, i, i + 1, 33);
    }

    addLane("connectTopL_1", 78, 220, 10);
    addLane("connectTopL_2", 226, 79, 10);
    addLane("connectTopR_1", 79, 230, 10);
    addLane("connectTopR_2", 236, 78, 10);

    int z = 243;
    for (int i = 230; i < 237; i++) {
        addLane("connectToSeaShip_" + i, i, z, 33);
        z += 3;
    }

    int x = 245;
    for (int i = 220; i < 227; i++) {
        addLane("connectToSeaShip_" + i, x, i, 33);
        x += 3;
    }

    int q = 240;
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i+=2){
        addLane("underBargeCrane_" +i, q, q+1, 10);
        addLane("underBargeCrane_" +i+1, q+1, q+2, 10);
        q+=3;
    }

    addLane("connectTopShip_1", 78, 240, 10);
    addLane("connectTopShip_2", 263, 79, 10);

    // Lets check from location Loc_a to Loc_b
    Graph graph = new Graph(nodes, edges);
    DijkstraAlgorithm dijkstra = new DijkstraAlgorithm(graph);
    dijkstra.execute(nodes.get(0));
    LinkedList<Vertex> path = dijkstra.getPath(nodes.get(256));

    for (Vertex vertex : path) {
        System.out.println(vertex);
    }
}

private void addLane(String laneId, int sourceLocNo, int destLocNo,
        int duration) {
    Edge lane = new Edge(laneId, nodes.get(sourceLocNo), nodes.get(destLocNo), duration);
    edges.add(lane);
}
}
```

this is the class with the shortest path

```
private void setWayPoints(){

    //Loop for the dockingCrane waypoints
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < dCraneArray.length; j++)
            {
                dCraneArray[j].add(new Waypoint(rootNode, assetManager));
                dCraneArray[j].get(i).setPosition(-15f+(j*200f), 0f, -685f);
            }
        }
        else if (i==1)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < dCraneArray.length; j++)
            {
                dCraneArray[j].add(new Waypoint(rootNode, assetManager));
                dCraneArray[j].get(i).setPosition(50f+(j*200f), 0f, -685f);
            }
        }
        else if (i==2)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < dCraneArray.length-1; j++)
            {
                dCraneArray[j].add(new Waypoint(rootNode, assetManager));
                dCraneArray[j].get(i).setPosition(105f+(j*200f), 0f, -685f);
            }   
            dCrane8.add(new Waypoint(rootNode, assetManager));
            dCrane8.get(i).setPosition(1529f, 0f, -685f);
        }
    }
    //Loop for the ShipCrane waypoints
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        //waypoint for entrance
        if(i==0){
            for(int j = 0; j < sCraneArray.length; j++)
            {
                if(j== sCraneArray.length-1){
                sCraneArray[j].add(new Waypoint(rootNode, assetManager));
                sCraneArray[j].get(i).setPosition(1595f, 0f, -368f+(j*144));
                }
                else{
                sCraneArray[j].add(new Waypoint(rootNode, assetManager));
                sCraneArray[j].get(i).setPosition(1595f, 0f, -461f+(j*144));
                }
            }   
        }
        //waypoint for center
        if(i==1){
            for(int j = 0; j < sCraneArray.length; j++)
            {
                sCraneArray[j].add(new Waypoint(rootNode, assetManager));
                sCraneArray[j].get(i).setPosition(1595f, 0f, -500f+(j*139f));
            }
        }
        //waypoint for exit
        if(i==2){
            for(int j = 0; j < sCraneArray.length; j++)
            {
                if(j==sCraneArray.length-1){
                sCraneArray[j].add(new Waypoint(rootNode, assetManager));
                sCraneArray[j].get(i).setPosition(1595f, 0f, -620f);
                }
                else{
                sCraneArray[j].add(new Waypoint(rootNode, assetManager));
                sCraneArray[j].get(i).setPosition(1595f, 0f, -440f+(j*144f));    
                }
            } 
        }
```

this is the waypoint class

Comment: What do you mean connect the two lists?

Comment: I have a method that can calculate the shortest path and each point has an Id, The id must be able to send a signal to the lLaneArray or a different array. nodes.get(0) must be the same as lLaneArray.get(0) and nodes.get  (250) must be the same as dCraneArray.get(4)

Comment: `list1.addAll(list2);`?

Comment: f_puras, that combines the list, i need to make a reference to another list